# Using PrimeNg locale with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, internationalization, locale, primeng, ngx-translate

I am trying to add the automatic translation for primeNg so I do not need to manually translate each message to the language I wish to use. I am using Angular 11 so I followed [the docs for V11 on localization](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v11/#/i18n), using [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core).

My issue is that the primeNg example uses English, and I seem to be missing something to actually make it work.

This is what I have so far:

In my app.module.ts, as per [ngx-translate explainations](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core):

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {

  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

@NgModule({
...
imports: [
  ...,
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
    loader: {
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
      deps: [HttpClient]
    }
  })
]
})
```

My app.component as per [primeNg's site](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v11/#/i18n):

```
constructor(private config: PrimeNGConfig, private translateService: TranslateService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.translateService.setDefaultLang('my_locale'); // 'my_locale is here instead of the language I actually use
    }

    translate(lang: string) {
        this.translateService.use(lang);
        this.translateService.get('primeng').subscribe(res => this.config.setTranslation(res));
    }
```

Because of [this site](https://phrase.com/blog/posts/angular-localization-i18n/), I also created a `my_locale.json` file under `assets/i18n`, where I put the following code:

```json
{
  "primeng": {
     "emptyMessage" : "my translation",
     "emptyFilterMessage" : "my translation"
  }
}
```

My expectation was that I would then see "my translation" instead of the default "No results found" when using a mutliselect for instance, but I saw no such change.

What am I missing/ lacking for this to work?

**EDIT**

Per comment request, I am including an example of my html code. Note that I have not touched it since attempting to add localization

```
<p-multiselect [options]="myOptions" [ngModel]="selectedOption"></p-multiselect>
```

NOTE: according to the [multiselect docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v11/#/multiselect), the messages for no records should default to the i18n translation

[image: screenshot from docs]

**EDIT 2**

I have tried adding the following to the app.component.ts, but neither helped:

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.translateService.addLangs(['my_locale']) // one attempt
        this.translateService.setDefaultLang('my_locale'); // 'my_locale' is here instead of the language I actually use
        this.translate('my_locale'); // second attempt
    }
```

Neither first attempt nor second nor using them together made any impact

Comment: share your html code too. @PMO1948

Comment: I added the html, but I did not see anywhere that I would need to edit it so I have not (yet)

Comment: everything are on same module or you have lazy load module too ? Because for lazy load module you have to add https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core#lazy-loaded-modules

Comment: Everything is in the same module. The project is not particularly large

Comment: Hello, actually your `translate()` method is not gets to calling. thats why this code is never working.

Comment: I thought that may be the problem, so I tried calling it in `ngOnInit` after the `this.translateService.setDefaultLang('my_locale');` but it made no difference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233084/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-pmo1948).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Demo [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-demo-qzvanh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

In your code your `translate()` method is not calling. Thats why your json file is not loading inside your component.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.primengConfig.ripple = true;
  this.translateService.setDefaultLang('my_locale');
}
ngAfterViewInit() {
   console.log('lang ');
   this.translateService.use('my_locale');
   this.translateService.get('primeng')
    .subscribe(res => this.primengConfig.setTranslation(res));
}
translate(lang: string) {
  console.log(lang);
  this.translateService.use(lang);
  this.translateService
   .get('primeng')
   .subscribe(res => this.primengConfig.setTranslation(res));
}
```

Now, default your `my_locate` file is loading. And when you want to chage to defautl `en` then call translate() method by on click of button.

```
<button (click)="translate('en')">Change Language to EN </button>
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Turns out I had a 2-fold problem - I was never calling the translate method, and I had an http-interceptor for mock-data that was getting in the way
Thanks for your help!